# Generalized Bézout theorem

Tags: matrices, polynomials, proof-verification

I am trying to verify the generalized Bézout theorem ([Little Bézout theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem) for matrix polynomial) through an example. The following is the problem formulation:
$\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}$

Show that the generalized Bézout theorem holds for an arbitrary $m$th-degree matrix polynomial
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}(x) = \vec{A}_{m}x^{m} + \vec{A}_{m - 1}x^{m - 1} + \dotsb + \vec{A}_{1}x + \vec{A}_{0},
\end{equation}
where $\vec{F} \in M_{n \times n}(K_{m}[x])$, and $K_{m}[x]$ is the set of all polynomials of degree $m$ or less in the indeterminate $x$ with coefficients in the field $K$.

Here is my attempt:

Define a linear divisor for $\vec{F}(x)$ as $\vec{D}(x) = x\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{C}$. Then
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  \vec{F}\vec{D}^{-1} &= (\vec{A}_{m}x^{m} + \vec{A}_{m - 1}x^{m - 1} + \dotsb + \vec{A}_{1}x + \vec{A}_{0})(x\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{C})^{-1} \\
  &= \left[\vec{A}_{m}(x\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{C})x^{m - 1} + (\vec{A}_{m - 1} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C})x^{m - 1}\right. \\
  & \qquad \left.\vphantom{\vec{A}_{m}^2}{} + \vec{A}_{m - 2}x^{m - 2} + \dotsb + \vec{A}_{1}x + \vec{A}_{0}\right](x\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{C})^{-1} \\
  &= \vec{A}_{m}x^{m - 1} + \left[(\vec{A}_{m - 1} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C})(x\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{C})x^{m - 2}\right. \\
  & \qquad {} + (\vec{A}_{m - 2} + \vec{A}_{m - 1}\vec{C} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C}^2)x^{m - 2} + \vec{A}_{m - 3}x^{m - 3} + \dotsb \\
  & \qquad\quad \left. {} + \vec{A}_{1}x + \vec{A}_{0}\vphantom{\vec{A}_{m}^2}\right](x\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{C})^{-1} \\
  &\hphantom{h} \vdots \\
  &= \vec{A}_{m}x^{m - 1} + (\vec{A}_{m - 1} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C})x^{m - 2} \\
  & \qquad + (\vec{A}_{m - 2} + \vec{A}_{m - 1}\vec{C} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C}^2)x^{m - 3} + \dotsb \\
  & \qquad\quad {} + (\vec{A}_{1} + \vec{A}_{2}\vec{C} + \dotsb + \vec{A}_{m - 1}\vec{C}^{m - 2} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C}^{m - 1}) + \dotsb \\
  & \qquad\qquad + (\vec{A}_{0} + \vec{A}_{1}\vec{C} + \dotsb + \vec{A}_{m - 1}\vec{C}^{m - 1} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C}^{m})(x\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{C})^{-1}.
 \end{split}
\end{equation}
Right-multiplying both sides of the equation above with $\vec{D}(x)$ gives
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  \vec{F}(x) &= \left[\vec{A}_{m}x^{m - 1} + (\vec{A}_{m - 1} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C})x^{m - 2} + \dotsb\right. \\
  & \qquad \left.{} + (\vec{A}_{1} + \vec{A}_{2}\vec{C} + \dotsb + \vec{A}_{m - 1}\vec{C}^{m - 2} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C}^{m - 1})\vphantom{\vec{A}_{m}^2}\right](x\vec{I}_{n} - \vec{C}) \\
  & \qquad\quad + \vec{A}_{0} + \vec{A}_{1}\vec{C} + \dotsb + \vec{A}_{m - 1}\vec{C}^{m - 1} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C}^{m},
 \end{split}
\end{equation}
the right remainder of which is
\begin{equation}
 \vec{R} = \vec{A}_{0} + \vec{A}_{1}\vec{C} + \dotsb + \vec{A}_{m - 1}\vec{C}^{m - 1} + \vec{A}_{m}\vec{C}^{m},
\end{equation}
and is equal to the right functional value of $\vec{F}(x)$ at $x = \vec{C}$. Similarly, the left remainder $\vec{\hat{R}}$ is obtained by evaluating $\vec{D}^{-1}\vec{F}$. This verifies the generalized Bézout theorem.

Note that all the matrices are square and of the same order.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: There are a lot of generalized Bezout thorems. What are you actually trying to prove? What are the $A_i$?

Comment: The theorem considered here is the generalized version of the [little Bézout theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem). The $A_{i}$ are square matrices.

Comment: Put that in the question, not comments. Readers should not be required to read comments to understand the question. @PYK

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Alright. I have added the details in the question.

Comment: It's much easier to solve this by induction on $m$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I see your point. Indeed, I used induction on the difference in degree between $F(x)$ and $D(x)$ to prove the matrix polynomial division algorithm and it was tedious, but that is because $\deg(D(x))$ is no longer restricted to 1.